# JQuery post not working when moving web-app to a win server 2003

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, windows, post, windows-server-2003

I have build a webapplication using ASP.NET MVC and JQuery. On my local machine this works fine,but when moving it to a Windows server 2003 the JQuery method post stops working. I'm also using the load method and this works fine.

```
function methodOne(id) {
    alert("debug1: <%= Url.Action( "MethodOne", "controller" ) + "/" %>" + id);
    $.post <%= Url.Action( "MethodOne", "controller" ) + "/" %>" + id, function(data) {
        alert("debug2");
        ...
        } else {
            alert("Debugg: Add presentation to user failed");
        }
     });
}
```

The debug2 is never outputed.

$('#panel').load("<%= Url.Action( "Method", "Controller" ) %>");

Works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your post function: opening parenthesis and quotes are missing. Also try passing an empty data as second argument to see if this works:

```
var url = '<%= Url.Action( "MethodOne", "controller" ) %>/' + id;
$.post(url, { }, function(data) {
    alert('success');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
The opening parenthesis and quotes was just a copy & paste failure. This is correct. I tried to pass the empty parameters. This is working on my local machine, but when moving it to the ms 2003 server it won't work

Comment: @karl, do you get some error? Can you try using FireBug and see if the request is sent and if the server responds?

Comment: Yeah you are right. I got a 404 error. The url is /mycustompage.htm?aspxerrorpath=/Controller/MethodOne/5. I don't know why the /mycustompage.htm?aspxerrorpath= is added but i'ts a start

Comment: hmm I also notice with firebug that it first makes the post, but after that also a Get with the same method. This doesn't exists. MethodOne doesn't return any view and I don't want to GET MethodOne. I thought the JQuery post only did the function added as a parameter?

Comment: I guess your controller action raises an exception and you are redirected to a custom page. Try calling it directly in your browser: `http://yourserver2k3/youapp/controller/MethodOne/5`. Activate tracing to see what exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks. I'v found the problem. Had nothing to the JQuery post to do